# Custom Jest Serializer with Enzyme

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

Are there any examples for how I would take a components with Enzyme's `shallow` render function and serialise it into a snapshot which is more readable?

I looked into the documentation for `addSnapshotSerializer` and tried to look into the code for `enzyme-to-json` without much luck.

In the end I came up with variations on,

```
expect.addSnapshotSerializer({
        test: v => true,
        print: (v, s) => Object.keys(s)
      });
```

But that didn't get me far either.

Suspect I am barking up the wrong tree!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/rogeliog/jest-serializer-enzyme?

> jest-serializer-enzyme
>
> This is a serializer for Enzyme backed by enzyme-to-json, I suggest
>   looking at enzyme-to-json for the implementation details
>
> Install it
>
> npm install --save-dev jest-serializer-enzyme Add it to your jest
>   config
>
> "jest": {   "snapshotSerializers":
>   ["/node_modules/jest-serializer-enzyme"] } More about Jest's
>   snapshotSerializer config here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json) which snapshot test your Enzyme wrappers.